# Does this JS IIFE correctly pass the event and parameters for an event handler?

Tags: javascript

After reviewing a few answers regarding how to pass in arguments to event handlers, I have implemented it using an IIFE which I've attached below.

The given handler code is just arbitrary to demonstrate the passing of variables.

The code appears to work, however I'm not 100% certain that I have correctly formed the closure - do I need to specify `a` and `b` as parameters somehow to the `return function(){..}`?

```
let selectedElem = document.querySelector("#targetDiv");
let var1 = 0;
let var2 = 10

selectedElem.addEventListener('click', ( (e, a, b) => {
    return function(e) {
        console.log(e, a, b);
        a += b;
        console.log(a);
    };
})(this.event, var1, var2));
```

Comment: What makes you think you need an IIFE for this?

Comment: You also have specified parameters `a` and `b`... those are `a` = 0, `b` = 10... Do you need them or not is up to you what you need.. If you put them into your constructor then pass them along.

Comment: I guess you're doing this just because you don't want `a` and `b` polluting the global scope. Which is fine, and as far as I can see this should work fine. Although I do find it a little confusing - I think it would be more understandable if you had the IIFE around the whole call to `selectedElem.addEventListener`, rather than using the IIFE just to create the callback function.) Anyway, if you're not 100% sure if you've done it right, have you tested it and looked at what's in the console?

Comment: @Adriani6 Ah, I meant to replace those with variable names, I'll edit the question now.

Comment: @NikKyriakides - I know that I could have a separate handler construction function, if that is what you're implying? I was using an IIFE as I felt it was more contained. 

Otherwise, I thought this would be necessary to pass in parameters to a handler function without relying on global variables?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I have console logged it, and it does return the expected values, however as its a new concept to me I wasn't entirely confident that I wasn't missing something subtle (as when I first tried to understand `this`)

Could you explain how I'd change this to make the entire call an IIFE?

Thanks for everyone's patience btw, I'm new to stackoverflow, and relatively new to JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not passing the event correctly. When you are creating the handler in the IIFE, there is no current event, and the global `this.event` should be undefined. You are not even using the `e` parameter of the IIFE, since you are shadowing it with the `e` parameter of the actual handler. You don't need the outer `e`, just drop it:

```
let selectedElem = document.querySelector("#targetDiv");
let var1 = 0;
let var2 = 10

selectedElem.addEventListener('click', ((a, b) => (e) => {
    console.log(e, a, b);
    a += b;
    console.log(a);
})(var1, var2));
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling I was missing something. Btw, I think you left out a final `)` in your answer - `...})(var1, var2));`